# Is frost build-up normal at the ingoing/outgoing pipes to the freezer evaporator?

Tags: refrigerator

[image]

Our freezer and fridge got worse and worse at cooling over the last week until yesterday I had to throw everything away.

I opened up the freezer and fresh food evaporator compartments. Both evaporators are doing some cooling. The fans for both are working.

The only thing that looks abnormal to me is this frost build-up in the freezer. But it's only at the incoming/outgoing evaporator pipes, not on the fins.

Is this normal?

Comment: Dirty Condenser Coils, Bad Evaporator Fan, Low Freon. See my answer ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can indicate a few possibilities:

1: You are low on freon - this means you have a leak.

2: Dirty Coils - bad cooling- causes the pipes to freeze up like in your picture. Check your condenser coils.

3: No Airflow - your fans on the evaporator inside are not working causing this same condition. Also check your fan from Fridge to Freezer ..

Check items 2 and 3 First.

**EDIT**

As was pointed out - I did not answer the question directly.

The Op Asked  *Is this normal?*

The direct answer: No this is not normal.

Comment: I know you're trying to help solve the actual problem. But this doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: how does lack of refrigerant cause ice buildup? It should just cause more compressor cycling?

Comment: @jiggunjer The whole process is based on flow rates for a given diameter of pipe and at a set pressure, low Freon means your pressure is going to be different, flow rate is different - so for given period of time the freon that does exist does not flow fast enough so in that area it absorbs more heat and the surrounding air moisture gets frozen thus ice. You can find more information on an engineering website, maybe some how it works sites. Same principle as dirty evap coils (no air flow). Refrigeration works on the principle of thermodynamics, absorb heat in one place and transfer to another.